# automated change management / version control

Tags: version-control, file-comparison, change-management

I'm looking for a tool (Windows) that indexes the contents of (clear) files in a directory and keeps a history of the changes made to these files.
This could be done persistent or in batch.

If possible it should include an integrated compare-tool so previous versions can be compared.

It's basically the Eclipse "Local history" view but as a separate tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize a Git repository in that folder and create a scheduled task that runs `git commit -am "periodic commit"` every X minutes (depending on the change rate). Then you can use the native history and diff capabilities of Git as you see fit.